# Defining a recursive function inside another function in C

Tags: c, recursion, function-definition

I'm trying to write a recursive function (`printPath`) inside another function (`dijkstraSSSP`), but it gives me a compiler error.

When I run `gcc dijkstra.c WGraph.c PQueue.c`, it compiles just fine. However, when I run `dcc -Wall -Werror -std=c11 -o dijkstra dijkstra.c WGraph.c PQueue.c`. I got this error:

```
dijkstra.c:48:38: error: function definition is not allowed here
void printPath (int currentNode) {
```

Which I think it is because I define a function inside another function. If this is the case, how should I modify the code?
Thanks a lot!

```
void dijkstraSSSP(Graph g, Vertex source) {
    int  dist[MAX_NODES];
    int  pred[MAX_NODES];
    bool vSet[MAX_NODES];  // vSet[v] = true <=> v has not been processed
    int s, t;

    PQueueInit();
    int nV = numOfVertices(g);
    for (s = 0; s < nV; s++) {
        joinPQueue(s);
        dist[s] = VERY_HIGH_VALUE;
        pred[s] = -1;
        vSet[s] = true;
    }

    dist[source] = 0;  

    int relaxWeight;
    for (s = 0; s < numOfVertices(g); s++) {
        s = leavePQueue(dist);
        //printf("iterating with s = %d\n", s);
        //printf("updating vSet[%d] = false\n", s);
        vSet[s] = false;
        for (t = 0; t < numOfVertices(g); t++) {
            //printf("iterating with t = %d\n", t);
            //printf("checking if s = %d is adj to t = %d and vSet[%d] = true\n", s, t, t);
            if (adjacent(g, s, t) != 0 && vSet[t] == true) {
                //printf("YES\n");
                relaxWeight = adjacent(g, s, t);
                if (dist[t] > dist[s] + relaxWeight) {
                    //printf("updating dist[%d] = dist[%d] + adjWeight[%d]\n", t, s, relaxWeight);
                    dist[t] = dist[s] + adjacent(g, s, t);
                    //printf("updating pred[%d] = %d\n", t, s);
                    pred[t] = s;
                }
            }
        }
    }
 
    void printPath (int currentNode) {
        if (pred[currentNode] == -1) {
            printf("%d", currentNode);
            return;
        } else {
            printPath (pred[currentNode]);
            printf("-%d", currentNode);
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < numOfVertices(g); i++) {
        if (dist[i] == VERY_HIGH_VALUE) {
            printf("%d: no path\n", i);
        } else{
            printf("%d: distance = %d, shortest path: ", i, dist[i]);
            printPath(i);
            printf("\n");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just move the function outside, to the global scope.

Comment: "inside another function" Why would you want to do this? Nested function definitions are not part of C standard. You would have to rely on compiler extensions.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm very new to C and still learning. The reason I did this is because I would have to use the value in the pred[] array which was computed as part of the dijkstraSSSP function

Comment: _"I think it is because I define a function inside another function."_ - you have rather answered your own question there haven't you?  So define it _outside_.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Defining a function inside another function is not defined in the C Standard. **gcc** allows it as an extension, but most compilers don't.

You should move the definition of `printPath` outside the body of the `dijkstraSSSP` function, before it in the source code, and pass `pred` as an extra argument:

```
void printPath(const int *pred, int currentNode) {
    if (pred[currentNode] == -1) {
        printf("%d", currentNode);
    } else {
        printPath(pred, pred[currentNode]);
        printf("-%d", currentNode);
    }
}

void dijkstraSSSP(Graph g, Vertex source) {
    int  dist[MAX_NODES];
    int  pred[MAX_NODES];
    bool vSet[MAX_NODES];  // vSet[v] = true <=> v has not been processed
    int s, t;

    PQueueInit();
    int nV = numOfVertices(g);
    for (s = 0; s < nV; s++) {
        joinPQueue(s);
        dist[s] = VERY_HIGH_VALUE;
        pred[s] = -1;
        vSet[s] = true;
    }

    dist[source] = 0;  

    int relaxWeight;
    for (s = 0; s < numOfVertices(g); s++) {
        s = leavePQueue(dist);
        //printf("iterating with s = %d\n", s);
        //printf("updating vSet[%d] = false\n", s);
        vSet[s] = false;
        for (t = 0; t < numOfVertices(g); t++) {
            //printf("iterating with t = %d\n", t);
            //printf("checking if s = %d is adj to t = %d and vSet[%d] = true\n", s, t, t);
            if (adjacent(g, s, t) != 0 && vSet[t] == true) {
                //printf("YES\n");
                relaxWeight = adjacent(g, s, t);
                if (dist[t] > dist[s] + relaxWeight) {
                    //printf("updating dist[%d] = dist[%d] + adjWeight[%d]\n", t, s, relaxWeight);
                    dist[t] = dist[s] + adjacent(g, s, t);
                    //printf("updating pred[%d] = %d\n", t, s);
                    pred[t] = s;
                }
            }
        }
    }
 
    for (int i = 0; i < numOfVertices(g); i++) {
        if (dist[i] == VERY_HIGH_VALUE) {
            printf("%d: no path\n", i);
        } else{
            printf("%d: distance = %d, shortest path: ", i, dist[i]);
            printPath(pred, i);
            printf("\n");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot! this resolved the issue. However I have 1 error left which I'm not too sure what causes the problem. When I run dcc -Wall -Werror -std=c11 -o dijkstra dijkstra.c WGraph.c PQueue.c again. I have the following error: dijkstra.c:67:13: error: implicit declaration of function 'printPath' is invalid in C99 [-Werror,-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
            printPath(pred, i);

Comment: I just realised that this is because I placed the printPath function underneath the dijkstraSSSP :)

Comment: @dtrinh: yes, either put a declaration or the definition of `printPath` before the definition of `dijkstraSSSP`.

Answer (score 1):

Move the definition of `printPath` outside of the body of `dijkstraSSSP` and, to give it access to `pred`, change it to accept two parameters instead of one. The additional parameter should have type `int *` and should point to the first element of `pred`.

In the call, pass `pred` for that new parameter. The array `pred` will be automatically converted to a pointer to its first element.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! yep, I changed the code to what you and chqrlie suggest and it worked.